# Liferay theme remove css

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme

I created new Theme in Liferay and now I want remove all default css from Welcome Page of Liferay, but I want keep this default css in admin panel.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have created a new theme, please apply that new theme on the welcome page. The new theme should contain all the css classes with custom look and feel that you want.

For e.g., if the welcome page has the login portlet, then please update the css classes that are used in the login portlet and have your desired look and feel in the theme.

The admin panel will not have your theme, it has default control panel theme.

Comment: I don't want update css, I want remove all css from welcome page, how?

Comment: creating a new theme is an extension to the liferay classic theme, if you want to remove the css, please add empty classes to your theme.

Comment: I use maven, so in src/main/webapp I created folder css and inside empty file main.css and is it all?

How can I create theme extension to the liferay classic theme?